# The method 'delayed' isn't defined for the type 'Function'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing a problem while upgrading my **Flutter** project from **version 2.10.0** to the **latest version**. I am receiving an error on the **`Future.delayed()`** function. I have done a lot of research, but I have been unable to resolve the issue. Please help me.

### **-> MY CODE**

```
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      setState(() {
        _applicationStatus = "Getting start...";
      });

      // Application Logo
      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      Object? applicationLogo = _prefs.get(SPConstants.appLogo);
      setState(() {
        _applicationLogo = applicationLogo != null
            ? ImageSourceConverter.converter(applicationLogo.toString())
            : null;
      setState(() {
        _applicationStatus = "Getting configuration...";
      });
      await _loadingConfig(context);
      Future.delayed( const Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
        setState(() {
          _applicationStatus = "Getting profile...";
        });
        await _validateLogin(context);
        await Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            LanguageScreen.routeName, (route) => false);
      });
      
    });
  }
```

### **-> THE ERROR PART ( `Future.delayed` )**

```
Future.delayed( const Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
    setState(() {
      _applicationStatus = "Getting profile...";
    });
    await _validateLogin(context);
    await Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        LanguageScreen.routeName, (route) => false);
  });
```

[image: The error Image]

Comment: Ctrl+click `Future`, where does it get you to?

Comment: and what you see if you `ctrl-click` when your mouse is over `Future`? seems you have some weird `import` defining `Future` as some function